# Explanation for "checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING"

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to understand this R CMD check warning for S3 function.

So, here is a completely reproducible example of my situation including R code and roxygen code. (I can never find a complete example of S3 anywhere and real-world usage in packages are either overly complicated or poorly documented. So, hopefully this is helpful to others implementing S3.)

```
#' @title An S3 generic.
#' @description An S3 generic that does something.
#' @param obj A numeric or character class object..
#' @param ... Other parameters are passed to methods.
#' @return Does something.
#' @export
#'
do_something <- function(obj, ...) {
  if(!class(obj) %in% c("numeric","character")) stop("obj must be character or numeric class.")
  UseMethod("do_something",obj)
}

#' @title An S3 method for obj class numeric.
#' @description An S3 method for obj class numeric.
#' @param obj A numeric class.
#' @param summary A character string.
#' @return Returns something.
#' @method do_something numeric
#' @rdname do_something.numeric
#' @importFrom stats median
#' @export
#' 
do_something.numeric <- function(obj, summary="mean") {
  
  if(summary=="mean") x <- mean(obj)
  if(summary=="median") x <- median(obj)
  
  return(x)
}

#' @title An S3 method for obj class character.
#' @description An S3 method for obj class character.
#' @param obj A character class.
#' @param collapse A character string.
#' @return Returns something.
#' @method do_something character
#' @rdname do_something.character
#' @export
#' 
do_something.character <- function(obj, collapse=",") {
  return(paste(obj,collapse=collapse))
}
```

I have an S3 generic `do_something()` that dispaches to method functions `do_something.numeric()` or `do_something.character()` based on the `obj` class. There are two method functions for the two different classes. And apart from the common shared argument `obj`, they have distinct arguments themselves.

The functions work as intended, but running R CMD check on this returns this.

```
> checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING
  do_something:
    function(obj, ...)
  do_something.character:
    function(obj, collapse)
  
  do_something:
    function(obj, ...)
  do_something.numeric:
    function(obj, summary)
  
  See section ‘Generic functions and methods’ in the ‘Writing R
  Extensions’ manual.

0 errors ✓ | 1 warning x | 0 notes ✓
Error: R CMD check found WARNINGs
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Now, I can fix this warning by adding `, ...` to method functions as well as the roxygen part. Here is the fixed code.

```
#' @title An S3 generic.
#' @description An S3 generic that does something.
#' @param obj A numeric or character class object..
#' @param ... Other parameters are passed to methods.
#' @return Does something.
#' @export
#'
do_something <- function(obj, ...) {
  if(!class(obj) %in% c("numeric","character")) stop("obj must be character or numeric class.")
  UseMethod("do_something",obj)
}

#' @title An S3 method for obj class numeric.
#' @description An S3 method for obj class numeric.
#' @param obj A numeric class.
#' @param summary A character string.
#' @param ... Other parameters
#' @return Returns something.
#' @method do_something numeric
#' @rdname do_something.numeric
#' @importFrom stats median
#' @export
#' 
do_something.numeric <- function(obj, summary="mean", ...) {
  
  if(summary=="mean") x <- mean(obj)
  if(summary=="median") x <- median(obj)
  
  return(x)
}

#' @title An S3 method for obj class character.
#' @description An S3 method for obj class character.
#' @param obj A character class.
#' @param collapse A character string.
#' @param ... Other parameters
#' @return Returns something.
#' @method do_something character
#' @rdname do_something.character
#' @export
#' 
do_something.character <- function(obj, collapse=",", ...) {
  return(paste(obj,collapse=collapse))
}
```

But, why!!??

To my understanding, the `...` in the generic is meant to signify additional arguments being passed to any of the method functions. In this case, `...` stands for arguments `summary` and/or `collapse`. And adding `...` makes sense to me if I had another internal function inside my method function like this.

```
do_something.character <- function(obj, collapse=",", ...) {
  x <- an_internal_function(obj=obj, collapse=collapse, ...)
  return(x)
}
```

But, I have no additional arguments to pass, so why do I need the `...` and what does it do here? Hopefully someone can clarify this.

R_4.0.0

Comment: Did you look at "‘Generic functions and methods’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual" as the warning suggested? You can find it here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Generic-functions-and-methods It says "A method must have all the arguments of the generic, including … if the generic does."

Comment: try `do_something(c(1, 2), summary = 'mean')` and `do_something(c('1', '2'), summary = 'mean')` with and without dots